# Trigger to copy formula into Lookup field

Tags: trigger, contact

I'm trying to create a trigger to copy before insert a formula field (the account of the contact "`"Contact__r.Account.Name`"") into a lookup field.

I tried this but I have problem (Illegal assiggnement from List to List )

```
trigger CopyValue on SurveyTaker__c (before insert) {
    for(SurveyTaker__c survey : trigger.new)
    {
        List<id> query;
        query = Database.query('SELECT id FROM Account WHERE Name =      
 \''+survey.AccountName__c+'\'  ');
       id accId = query[0];
        survey.Account_Survey_Contact__c = query[0];
   }

}
```

Is there any way to change the record type to be able to copy this value?

Thanks,

Comment: first don't query in for loop. second change `List<id> query` to` List<account> query`. use map for bulkification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can greatly simplify this by:

- Creating a formula on the `SurveyTaker__c` object that references the Account Id.  We'll call this `AccountId__c`
- Simply update the `Account_Survey_Contact__c` field with the value in your new `AccountId__c` field, via a trigger.

I don't recall off the top of my head whether a lookup field can be updated via the Process Builder

Your trigger would then look like:

```
trigger CopyValue on SurveyTaker__c (before insert) {
    for(SurveyTaker__c survey : trigger.new)
    {
        survey.Account_Survey_Contact__c = survey.AccountId__c;
    }
}
```

As an FYI, there are a few issues with your current trigger:

- SOQL query in for loop
- SOQL query vulnerable to SOQL injection.  Use `List<Account> accs = [SELECT id FROM Account WHERE Name IN :survey.AccountName__c];` instead.  Although the `survey.AccountName__c` would need to be replaced with a list of account names that you'd have to determine before entering that for loop.
- querying accounts but storing them in a list of Ids.

Answer (score 0):

*Try something like this, it worked for me*

```
List<Account> query;

 query = [SELECT id FROM Account WHERE Name =: survey.sked__Region__c];

id accId = query[0].id;
```